# Configure App using CSOM c#

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, csom, pnp

I am able to install/deploy an app to a sharepoint site using the code below

```
var appManager = new AppManager(context);
var apps = appManager.GetAvailable();
var foundApp = apps.Where(a => a.Id == FeatureId).FirstOrDefault();
var installAppAsync = await appManager.InstallAsync(foundApp);
```

However, one particular app needs to be tied to a specific document library when added to a site, how can I specify these parameters when installing the app?

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing a custom command set for a list, after installing the SPFx package to the app catalog, you need to attach your command set to the target list with the code:

```
var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(listId);
var customActions = list.UserCustomActions;

var customAction = customActions.Add();
customAction.ClientSideComponentId = new Guid("Id of your command set");
customAction.Location = "ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar";
customAction.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Please, note that your package must be either tenant-wide scoped or deployed to the app catalog of the target site collection.

Comment: There is a mixture of Apps that I need to add, some are ProviderHostedEventReceivers, others are commands like your example.  Its the EventReceivers and the like that I need to add to the site.

Comment: You cannot attach event receivers with an app, you can do that programmatically only: https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2014/01/add-delete-and-list-remote-event-receivers.html